# How to give border radius for button?

Tags: flutter

How to add border radius for `OutlinedButton` and `ElevatedButton` with background color
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below example :

in ElevatedButton Example :

```
 ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Add your button click logic here
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(10.0), 
                side: BorderSide(
                    width: 2,
                    color: Colors.green),
              ),
              backgroundColor:
                  Colors.red, 
            ),
            child: Text('My Button'),
          ),
```

In OutlineButton Example :

```
OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
             
            },
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              side: BorderSide(
                width: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(10.0), // Adjust the radius as needed
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('My Button'),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code I have write code on your provided images, some reference URL below

[OutlinedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html), [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html), [Style Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html)

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
        fixedSize: const Size(200, 50), //Add width and height on your need
      ),
      child: const Text(
        'Clear',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        fixedSize: const Size(200, 50), //Add width and height on your need
      ),
      child: const Text('Apply'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]